# Symfony 4: ENV in phpunit.xml.dist

Tags: symfony4

For functional tests to work in Symfony 4, I have to add an `<env .../>` tag to `phpunit.xml.dist` which specified the database credentials.

What I find awkward about this is that `phpunit.xml.dist` is of course committed to VCS. This implies that the database credentials, which usually are – at least if not using Docker – host-specific, are committed to VCS. (Plus: the environment settings might contain sensitive data. For both reasons, the Symfony docs say that `.env` should not be committed to VCS.)

Isn’t there a more sensible way to handle this? I’d love PHPUnit to just use the configuration from `.env`. Isn’t that possible? I am aware that I can just specify ENV variables at the shell or export them from `.bashrc`, `.profile` or the like, but either the test invocation is more complex or I have a bunch of project configuration outside the project. Or I could script that myself and have the shell check for the existence of an `.env` file in the `pwd` and automatically set that for the next command, but that seems like quite some overhead …

(By the way: using SQLite is not a solution, as SQLite is not suitable for our needs. Moreover, the database credentials are just one example. There might be other settings that need to be configured using `<env>` as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `phpunit.xml`. If `phpunit.xml` exists, PHPUnit will read its documentation from it instead of from `phpunit.xml.dist`.

I am not sure whether there is a way to combine the two configuration files. (It seems that `phpunit.xml.dist` is completely ignored by PHPUnit if `phpunit.xml` exists.) If not then this might not be really helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I hadn’t used `phpunit.xml` in a while, so this didn’t come to my mind. However, this is still more awkward than how things where with Symfony3. We’ll see if time will bring improvements in this regard …